# Javascript: use conditions in var declare

Tags: javascript

I need to declare an email template for later use (for send_email API call), in the template that has some variables. My question is how can I skip HTML part according to some conditions. (The `this.var` part comes from vuejs)
Or if there is any better way to do this?

For example:

```js
  let email_template = `
    <table>
      <tr><td><b>Submitor</b></td><td>${this.loginUser.username}</td></tr>
      <tr><td><b>Order Type</b></td><td>${this.order}</td></tr>
      <tr><td><b>Goods</b></td><td>${this.goods}</td></tr>
      <tr><td><b>Fee</b></td><td>${this.fee} </td></tr>
    </table>
    <p>Please let me know if you have any questions.</p>
  `;
```

How can I not include the Fee table record if `${isFree}` is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest another template literal inside at the `fee` section, and either list the fee `<tr>` or the empty string:

```
let email_template = `
<table>
  <tr><td><b>Submitor</b></td><td>${this.loginUser.username}</td></tr>
  <tr><td><b>Order Type</b></td><td>${this.order}</td></tr>
  <tr><td><b>Goods</b></td><td>${this.goods}</td></tr>
  ${isFree ? '' : `<tr><td><b>Fee</b></td><td>${this.fee} </td></tr>`}
</table>
<p>Please let me know if you have any questions.</p>
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this syntax for the same. Here string addition is done with if condition check;

```
let email_template = "";

email_template = email_template + `
       <table>
             <tr><td><b>Submitor</b></td><td>${this.loginUser.username}</td></tr>
             <tr><td><b>Order Type</b></td><td>${this.order}</td></tr>
             <tr><td><b>Goods</b></td><td>${this.goods}</td></tr>`;                     
if(!isFee)
{
   email_template = email_template + `
              <tr><td><b>Fee</b></td><td>${this.fee} </td></tr>
           </table>`;
}
```

Comment: thanks man, but this will not keep the order if the fee item is in the middle.

Comment: You have to tweak this code to make it work in middle. This is just for logic, like how you can solve your problem.